# If else statement returning else condition even when condition is true python

Tags: python

[image: Else is executed]

the if else statement is not working for me

Comment: In your own words, what do you think `/` does? What do you think the result of `2 / 2` should be, and why?

Comment: You are using wrong operator in if condition. `/` gives quotient and you require remainder.

Comment: I think you are looking for the % operator

Answer (score 3):

```
print('Hello There')
number=int(input('please provide a number'))

if number%2==0:
    print ('even')
else:
    print('odd')
```

Just read about the `modulus %`

Answer (score 0):

`/` is the division operator. If you want to check for evenness vs oddness, you should be looking at the remainder, and using the module (`%`) operator:

```py
if number % 2 == 0:
    print("even")
else:
    print("odd")
```